# Type assertion to an embedded type from interface{}

Tags: go

I want to use type assertion from `interface{}` to a type I sure the content of the `interface{}` has embedded reference of. https://play.golang.org/p/G8YrS7WZyQU

```
package main
import "fmt"

type S1 struct {}
type S2 struct {*S1}

func main() {
    s := interface{}(&S2{&S1{}})

    // I do not know the s type, but know that it is of `struct {*S1}`
    _, ok := s.(*S1)
    fmt.Println(ok)
}
```

Is it even possible in Go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do this. The spec says that you can only type-assert an interface to a type that is *identical* to the type of the value that was stored in the interface. It also says "A [defined type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions) is always different from any other type". Structurally compatible isn't good enough; the only type you can use in your assertion is `S2`.

Reflection would be possible (see that the value has a `Kind` of `Struct`, and has a `Field` which is a `Pointer` which has an `Elem` with a `Type` that equals `reflect.TypeOf(S1{})`), at which point an assertion to `S1` would succeed on that elem's `Interface` (but *not* an assertion to the embedding type).